# Suppress display of "NA" in tableGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table that I'd like to plot alongside a ggplot2 plot using a tableGrob. For output purposes, I would like to suppress NA from being printed.

Example:

```
library(RGraphics) # support of the "R graphics" book, on CRAN
library(gridExtra) 

tab <- head(iris)
tab[1,2] <- NA # set a couple values to NA for example purposes
g1 <- tableGrob(tab)

#"Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
g2 <- qplot(Sepal.Length,  Petal.Length, data=iris, colour=Species)
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=1, main="The iris data")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data table you are plotting is stored in element `g1$d`.

```
 g1$d
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1          NA          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

As just replacing `NA` with `""` will convert column to character and loose formatting, first, data frame columns should be converted to character, then `NA` value replaced and data structure converted back to data frame (to get rid of quotes).

```
g1$d<-apply(g1$d,2,as.character)
g1$d[is.na(g1$d)]<-""
g1$d<-as.data.frame(g1$d)
g1$d
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1                      1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=1, main="The iris data")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the built in formatting of the tableGrob relies on the data type contained in the table. So, setting the NA values to "" casts the whole column to a string type. This results in things like 3.0 being formatted as 3, which is not what I want. In addition, if I had larger values pretty printed with commas (e.g. 3,456,789), those would suffer a similar fate.

Comment: You're right. That is ugly, but it gets the job done. Thanks!